# Jasmine Spies Not Working

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Given the following code (with Jasmine included in the page):

```
  function MyCtorFn() {
    this.myMethod = function() {
          console.log("hello world")
      }
  }

  //arrange
  var myCtrFn = new MyCtorFn();
  spyOn(myCtrFn, 'myMethod');

  //act
  myCtrFn.myMethod();
```

Why does the following return undefined?

```
myCtrFn.myMethod.callCount
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documented way to get the call count for a spy is via the `calls` property:

```
myCtrFn.myMethod.calls.count() // 1
```

Documentation: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-23

Looking at the sources, it seems this information is not available anywhere else: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/CallTracker.js
https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/base.js#L75

Answer (score 5):

`.callCount` is a property of the `spy`.

```
function MyCtorFn() {
this.myMethod = function() {
      console.log("hello world")
  }
}

//arrange
var myCtrFn = new MyCtorFn();
var spy = spyOn(myCtrFn, 'myMethod');

//act
myCtrFn.myMethod();

spy.callCount; // 1
```

---

Actually, it's very strange that it doesn't work, since the `spyOn` method should replace the original method with the spy.

See `https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js` line `582`.

Personally I think that is very strange behavior. This would cause all kinds of incompatibilities with other frameworks. What if you had two instances of jasmine and they both try to spy on the same function? Very strange.

This is why I assumed the properties were only on the spy.

The whole point of a spy is that you're undetectable right?

```
var trustedFunction = function () {};
var obj = {
    foo: trustedFunction
}
spyOn(obj, "foo");
obj.foo === trustedFunction; // false? BUSTED
```

Perhaps a **spy** is not the right analogy. A `CallTrackerWrapper` would be a much less nefarious and more humble name.

Comment: Alternatively, i think you could use `myCtrFn.myMethod.calls.count()` http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-23

Comment: @Ben: Apparently it's not just you, unless you wrote [this cheatsheet](http://tobyho.com/2011/12/15/jasmine-spy-cheatsheet/) which clearly shows `callCount` being where you thought it would be.

Comment: That cheatsheet is over 2 years old though so maybe jasmine changed the implementation? I'm always weary of 3rd party information.

Comment: `spy.callCount` does not work for me, but `spy.calls.count()` does. Also can anyone tell me how to reset the spy?

Comment: The documentation i linked to does :P. `myCtrFn.myMethod.calls.reset()`

Comment: To reset the spy use `spy.calls.reset()`.

Comment: I added the calls.count() method as a separate answer, because it doesn't seem that this one is working.